# Bitcoin And BitcoinCash Input Value

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, segregated-witness, bitcoin-cash

According to bip 143 (https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0143.mediawiki), bitcoin transaction has the information about the input value as part of the witness.

i heard bitcoincash has also a solution for validating the input value (without going through all the blockchain), but i cant find this information in a transaction.

i tried to find it and read about the bch transaction structure and the only thing i found is this proposal: https://github.com/bitcoincashorg/bitcoincash.org/blob/master/spec/replay-protected-sighash.md

and im not sure if its indeed deployed into the bch blockchain.

is there any solution for this problem in bitcoincash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compliance with the "Replay Protected Sighash" is required in all BCH transactions since the BTC-BCH chain split, while on Bitcoin BIP143 is only required for spending SegWit outputs.

[Here is how it helps offline signing](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=181734.0) if you want to know how it was invented.

Update:

> has the information about the input value as part of the witness.

Note that the witness contains the signed hash that contains the value of the UTXO, but not the value of the UTXO itself.

If I missed one of your questions, let me know by commenting.